# Parse Text File in C - Skip Lines - Repeated Calculation

Tags: c, parsing, text, line, skip

I have been spinning my wheels for a while trying to figure this out but have not been able to.  Hope you can help!

I am currently working on a program that solves Sudoku.  The current code that I am showing below takes in as input a 9x9 grid of integers (the Sudoku puzzle) and then generates a solution.  This is working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isAvailable(int puzzle[][9], int row, int col, int num)
{
    int rowStart = (row/3) * 3;
    int colStart = (col/3) * 3;
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<9; ++i)
    {
        if (puzzle[row][i] == num) return 0;
        if (puzzle[i][col] == num) return 0;
        if (puzzle[rowStart + (i%3)][colStart + (i/3)] == num) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int fillSudoku(int puzzle[][9], int row, int col)
{
    int i;
    if(row<9 && col<9)
    {
        if(puzzle[row][col] != 0)
        {
            if((col+1)<9) return fillSudoku(puzzle, row, col+1);
            else if((row+1)<9) return fillSudoku(puzzle, row+1, 0);
            else return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=0; i<9; ++i)
            {
                if(isAvailable(puzzle, row, col, i+1))
                {
                    puzzle[row][col] = i+1;
                    if((col+1)<9)
                    {
                        if(fillSudoku(puzzle, row, col +1)) return 1;
                        else puzzle[row][col] = 0;
                    }
                    else if((row+1)<9)
                    {
                        if(fillSudoku(puzzle, row+1, 0)) return 1;
                        else puzzle[row][col] = 0;
                    }
                    else return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int row,column;
    int puzzle[9][9];
    //printf("Enter your input:\n");
    for (row=0; row <9; row++){
       for(column = 0; column <9; column ++){
       scanf("%d",&puzzle[row][column]);
       }
    }

    //PRINT INPUT PUZZLE
    printf("Original Puzzle:");
    printf("\n+-----+-----+-----+\n");
    for(i=1; i<10; ++i)
    {
        for(j=1; j<10; ++j) printf("|%d", puzzle[i-1][j-1]);
        printf("|\n");
        if (i%3 == 0) printf("+-----+-----+-----+\n");
    }
    printf("\n");


    //PRINT OUTPUT PUZZLE
    printf("Solved Puzzle:");
    if(fillSudoku(puzzle, 0, 0))
    {
        printf("\n+-----+-----+-----+\n");
        for(i=1; i<10; ++i)
        {
            for(j=1; j<10; ++j) printf("|%d", puzzle[i-1][j-1]);
            printf("|\n");
            if (i%3 == 0) printf("+-----+-----+-----+\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    else printf("\n\nNO SOLUTION\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I now want to use a text file from Project Euler (https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p096_sudoku.txt) and have my program generate all 50 of these solutions.  The text file has the following format:

```
Grid 01
003020600
900305001
001806400
008102900
700000008
006708200
002609500
800203009
005010300
Grid 02
200080300
060070084
030500209
000105408
000000000
402706000
301007040
720040060
004010003
...
```

and so on for 50 total grids.

My question is: What is the best way to parse through this file to

1. Skip over the "Grid ##" line
2. Read in the next 9 lines for input
3. Continue on through the file to repeat the program until the end of the file

EDIT:
Between steps 2 & 3, this is what would happen:
After I read in 9 lines of numbers, I'll use that as input to the program and have the program run and generate a solution, and then look back to the input file and get the next set of numbers and run another iteration of the program.

Thank you for any input and guidance you can provide me!
-Colton

Comment: Sudoku commonly uses *numbers* as symbols, while the separator seems to start with a character. I'd recommend `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`.

Comment: @EOF: But if the file has a fixed/regular format (as this seems to), what OP proposes will be fine.

Comment: @ScottHunter: The approach to solving this problem seems clear enough to me.  What I am unsure of is a simple way to parse through this fixed format file to get the input I need to feed to the program for each iteration.

Comment: @ColtonRudd: If the input file layout is as regular/fixed as it seems, your approach to reading in each problem is fine.  If there is some part of handling each individual Sudoku problem at issue, you'll need to spell out that question.

Comment: @TobyAllen This question is asking for help with additional implementation, it does not belong on Code Review. Please read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: @ScottHunter I apologize if I'm not being clear enough.  I'm still new to this.  Here's how I want the program to work (or think it should): I run the program and pass in a text file as input that contains 50+ Sudoku puzzles in the format listed above.  The program should check to see if it is at the end of the file, and if not, look at the next grid (puzzle), solve it, and then return the solution.  The program should then loop and get the next puzzle from the file, solve it, return it, and loop until it has reached the end of the file and there are no more puzzles to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When data in a text file is *line* formatted, strongly recommend using `fgets()`.

Consider each group of 10 lines as a record.  They belong together, if 1 part is in error, the whole group is invalid.

```
// return 0 on success, -1 on EOF and 1 on format failure
int ReadPuzzle(FILE *inf, int puzzle[][9], int *Grid) {
  char buffer[20]; // About 2x expected need

  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, inf) == NULL)
    return -1;  // File EOF or IO error occurred.
  if (sscanf(buffer, "Grid %d", Grid) != 1)
    return 1;

  for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, inf) == NULL)
      return 1;  // If Grid line exists, 9 lines _should_ follow
    char *p = buffer;
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
      // Use %1d to limit scanning to 1 digit
      if (sscanf(p, "%1d", &puzzle[row][col]) != 1)
        return 1;
      p++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Checks could be added to insure extra data is not on the lines.

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown! In looking at the main function to implement the ReadPuzzle function you created, instead of calling for the scanf inside the nested for loops, would I just need to declare a couple of extra variables to pass in as arguments and then make a call to ReadPuzzle using those? Also, would I need to set up an additional loop to continue parsing through the file until it reaches EOF?

Comment: @Colton Rudd  Yes you have the right idea.  Call `ReadPuzzle()` after opening the file to get 1 puzzle.  If the return value is 0, success!  Else the return value <0 and you are done.  If the return value is >0, something is wrong in the file or code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do some stuff between steps 2 & 3, but what you outline sounds reasonable.

Comment: After I read in 9 lines of numbers, I'll use that as input to the program and have the program run and generate a solution, and then look back to the input file and get the next set of numbers and run another iteration of the program.  That's what I would say comes between 2 & 3 if that makes sense.

Comment: @ColtonRudd: Makes perfect sense; you just didn't say it initially.

Comment: I'll go back and edit and make the clarification.  Thank you!